# How to limit text width

Tags: html, css

I would like to limit the width of a block of text so it will look like it has br at the ned of each line.

Something like this:

```
Texttttttttttttttttttttt
tttttttttttttttttttttttt
tttttttttttttttttttttttt
```

From this:

Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

I have tried to specify the div's or p's width, but it didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can apply css like this:

```
div {
   word-wrap: break-word;
   width: 100px;
}
```

Usually browser does not break words, but `word-wrap: break-word;` will force it to break words too.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mp7tc/

More info about [word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap)

Comment: if this doesn't solve it, try,

`word-wrap: 'break-word;'`
`white-space: 'normal;'`

Answer (score 15):

```
 display: inline-block;
max-width: 80%;
height: 1.5em;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<div style="max-width:200px; word-wrap:break-word;">Texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</div>
```

Comment: max-width is not enough: http://jsfiddle.net/Mp7tc/1/ You also need to tell browser that it can break words, as it will add line break symbol only after words (instead of spaces or something like that)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `word-wrap : break-word;`

Answer (score 1):

use css property `word-wrap: break-word;`

see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/emgRF/

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
     p{
         width:     70%
         word-wrap: break-word;
     }
</style>
```

This wasn't working in my case. It worked fine after adding following style.

```
<style>
     p{
        width:     70%
        word-break: break-all;
     }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many answers here are very good and quite similar.  My concern was specifying width in pixels, which means text might look scrunched-up in high-resolution screens.  Better to specify width in terms of maximum characters in a row.  I also like to specify styling inside the `<div>` for small, one-file index.html projects.  For realistic projects, off-course, the styling should go into a separate css file.

```
<div style="word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 50ch;>Your text goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style> 
p
{
    width:100px; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
</style>

<p>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit.Fusce non nisl
non ante malesuada mollis quis ut ipsum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras ut adipiscing dolor. Nunc congue, 
tellus vehicula mattis porttitor, justo nisi sollicitudin nulla, a rhoncus lectus lacus 
id turpis. Vivamus diam lacus, egestas nec bibendum eu, mattis eget risus</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to wrap long text without spaces.

look at this :[Hyphenator.js](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) and it's [demo](http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%204.0.0/WorkingExample.html).

Comment: JavaScript isn't necessary if he can do that just with css, or?

Comment: This is a link-only "answer", which does not adhere to SO policy for answers. All answers must be self-contained for quality, or the event that the page becomes unreachable. Also, it's just a link, not an actual answer. As is, this would make an excellent comment to the post. Comments can be hints, or links, and do not require devoting time or effort normally required of full answers. Please `edit` to include the essential info from the pages you reference. Source links are always encouraged to supplement your answer. Reference the [help pages](https://stackoveflow.com/help) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
word-break:break-all;
```

did the job for me

from:

qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq

to:

qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq

qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq

qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq

qqqqqqqqqqq

```
word-wrap: ...
```

did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
   word-wrap: break-word;
   width: 100px;
}
```

The answer which is signed correct should be updated code like this:

```
div {
   word-wrap: break-word;
   width: 100%;
}
```

100px not but 100%.